Regex for nested tag detection
I have a document generation application that handles tag replacement, I use a regular expression to detect said tags. These tags can be of multiple types, for the sake of the problem let's take into account the following:

{{text to replace::S}} -  Simple tag, in-line text replacement
{{content to include::C}} - Choice tag, allows the user to include, or not, the tag content.
{{option 1 / option 2::A}} - Alternative tag, allows the user to choose between option 1 or option 2

I've worked with these without a problem and detected them using this RegeX expression /\{\{([^:]+)::([S|C|R|A])\}\}/g
I want to introduce nested tags at the maximum level of 1, and that's where the problem is. I've tried multiple approaches.
First approach Try it here
/\{\{([^{]+(?:\{\{[^{}]*\}\})?)::([S|C|R|A])\}\}/g this allows me to detect only one nested tag but, as you can see the Alternative tag has problems with it.
Second approach Try it here
/\{\{(.+(?:\{\{[^{}]*\}\})?)::([S|C|R|A])\}\}/g this detects multiple nested tags but, when a text has multiple tags it breaks.
Any help?

Regular expressions are not good at handling nestable patterns.

@Barmar found the solution. I believe that would be the case when the nesting level is over 2. For my use case, it is limited to 1

Found the solution: /\{\{([^{}]*(?:\{\{[^{}]*\}\}[^{}]*)*)::([SCRA])\}\}/g

I can't see how you can use that to parse nested structures such as ... {{... {{...::A}} ...::A}} ... {{... {{... {{...::A}} ...::A}} ...::A}} .... Short of using an LL parser and tree parser you can use regular expressions if you temporarily annotate the nesting level. See details at https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3

@PeterThoeny, I can't, for my use case, where the nesting level is always <= 1, it works. I'll specify this detail in the question.
